# How to properly find java home folder with batch?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, windows-registry, java

I'm trying to find the currently installed version and home folder of java JDK.

I am trying this code, but I cannot figure out the proper "combination" of delims, tokens such that it ignores the space in the path.

```
@echo off
rem "JavaHome    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2"
setlocal
for /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK" /v "CurrentVersion"') DO (set java_version=%%A)
rem echo C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-%java_version%
for /F "tokens=3-5 " %%B in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK\%java_version%" /v "JavaHome"') DO (set java_home=%%B)


echo %java_version%
echo "%java_home%"

endlocal
pause
```

I've tried using tab character for delims, I've tried 4 spaces since that's what the string uses, still I get either empty string `""` or I get just `"C:\Program"` for the second variable `java_home`

Comment: Isn't the ````echo %JAVA_HOME%```` environment variable already defined with the installation of Java? https://www.baeldung.com/find-java-home

Comment: in Windows %JAVA_HOME% variable is not set automatically by the installer.

Comment: How about the  ````where java```` as mentioned in that link?

Comment: `where java` points out to the executable `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\java.exe`. I guess I could remove the end part of the string to get the path but I now see there's another issue here: my latest version is `17.0.2` but with `where java` I get `14.0.2`

Comment: I probably should mention that I also tried the `java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | findstr "java.home"` but the format of that output string doesn't give much options to get just the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try:

```powershell
@echo off & setlocal

for /F tokens^=2* %%A in ('
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK" /v "CurrentVersion"
   ')do set "_java_version=%%~B"
   
echo C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-%_java_version%

for /F tokens^=2* %%A in ('
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK\%_java_version%" /v "JavaHome"
   ')do set "_java_home=%%~B" 
   
echo %_java_version% & echo "%_java_home%"
   
endlocal & pause
```

---

**Obs. 1:** Run as administrator

---

**Obs. 2:** Use "`\`" for reg key and "`-`" for path folder:

```powershell
:: "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK       \      %_java_version%" 
::                     ...\JDK   +   \  +   %_java_version%"

:: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk       -       %_java_version%" 
::                    ...\jdk   +   -  +    %_java_version%"
```

---

**Obs. 3:** To set a system variable, then use the **[`setx`](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)** command

```powershell
@echo off & setlocal

for /F tokens^=2* %%A in ('
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK" /v "CurrentVersion"
   ')do set "_java_version=%%~B"
   
echo C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-%_java_version%

for /F tokens^=2* %%A in ('
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK\%_java_version%" /v "JavaHome"
   ')do set "_java_home=%%~B" 
   
setx /M java_home "%_java_home%"
setx /M java_version "%_java_version%"

echo %_java_version% & echo "%_java_home%"
endlocal & pause
```

---

> *I probably should mention that I also tried the:*
> *`java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | findstr "java.home"`*
> *but the format of that output string doesn't give much options to get just the path.*
>
> This attempt ported to a loop and substring can get what you want without having to run as an administrator....

```powershell
@echo off & setlocal

for /f tokens^=2* %%A in ('
2^>^&1 java -XshowSettings:properties -version ^| find /i "a.h"
   ')do set "_java_home=%%~B" && set "_ver=%%~nxB" 

set "_java_version=%_ver:*-=%"
echo %java_version% & echo "%java_home%" 

endlocal & pause
```

Or without using substring but with two `For` loops:

```powershell
@echo off & setlocal

for /f tokens^=2* %%A in (
'2^>^&1 java -XshowSettings:properties -version^|find "a.h"
    ')do set "_java_home=%%~B"
    
for /f tokens^=2delims^=^" %%A in ('
2^>^&1 java -XshowSettings:properties -version^|findstr \^"
    ')do set "_java_version=%%~A"

echo\%_java_home% # %_java_version%
   
endlocal & pause
```

---

**Obs. 4.** If you are going to make use of this option and add the command `Setx /m`, then it will be necessary to run as administrator:

```powershell
@echo off & setlocal

for /f tokens^=2* %%A in ('
2^>^&1 java -XshowSettings:properties -version ^| find /i "a.h"
   ')do set "_java_home=%%~B" && set "_ver=%%~nxB" 

set "_java_version=%_ver:*-=%"

setx /M java_home "%_java_home%"
setx /M java_version "%_java_version%"

endlocal & pause
```